# Swift 3 - Set navigation bar and body view image

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift3, uinavigationbar

I want to have a view controller with navigation bar and main view looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, just set navigation bar to transparent:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

and set UIImageView to fit full screen